# Remove s-maxage from Cache-Control header using Varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

We're currently using the `s-maxage` directive in the Cache-Control header from our origin to control the TTL in Varnish. However, I'd like to remove it from the response before delivery, so that no other caches in the request chain act on it.

I'm currently looking at the header VMOD, to remove `s-maxage` from the header, but leave the rest of it intact. I believe this could be achieved with something like this:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    header.regsub(resp, "s-maxage=[0-9]+,?\s?", "")
}
```

As a newcomer to Varnish, I wanted to sanity-check this approach and make sure there isn't a better way to tackle it?

Appreciate any support or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Replace header at delivery time

The following VCL snippet will strip off the `s-maxage` attribute from the `Cache-Control` header before it is sent to the client.

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    set resp.http.cache-control = regsub(resp.http.cache-control,
"(,\s*s-maxage=[0-9]+\s*$)|(\s*s-maxage=[0-9]+\s*,)","");
}
```

### Replace header at storage time

It is also possible to strip off this attribute from the `Cache-Control` header before it gets stored into a cache object. In that case, you'll use the `beresp.http.cache-control` variable inside `vcl_backend_response`.

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.cache-control = regsub(beresp.http.cache-control,
"(,\s*s-maxage=[0-9]+\s*$)|(\s*s-maxage=[0-9]+\s*,)","");
}
```

### Using vmod_headerplus

If you're using *Varnish Enterprise*, you can use the [`vmod_headerplus`](https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/headerplus/) module to easily delete header attributes:

```
vcl 4.1;

import headerplus;

sub vcl_deliver {
    headerplus.init(resp);
    headerplus.attr_delete("Cache-Control","s-maxage",",");
    headerplus.write();
}
```

```
vcl 4.1;

import headerplus;

sub vcl_backend_response {
    headerplus.init(beresp);
    headerplus.attr_delete("Cache-Control","s-maxage",",");
    headerplus.write();
}
```

Although *Varnish Enterprise* is the commercial version of *Varnish Cache*, you can still use it without upfront license payments if you use it on AWS, Azure or GCP.

- [Varnish Enterprise on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Varnish-Software-Inc-Varnish-Enterprise-6-Ubuntu/prodview-atq2qasjkejio)
- [Varnish Enterprise on Azure](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/varnish.varnish-enterprise)
- [Varnish Enterprise on GCP](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/varnish-public/varnish-enterprise-6-payg-ubuntu)

Comment: Wow Thijs, that's an excellent and comprehensive answer. Thanks so much.